# codeigniter Maximum execution time of 3600 seconds

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I use codeigniter and i have this error:

> Maximum execution time of 3600 seconds.

I'd like to put in my code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

The question is, where should i put that code? in controllers or models?

Comment: a better question is why are you getting that error (the code ran for 1h???)? don't put a bandaid, fix the problem.

Comment: i have a function to import ms. excel file to database. each row will be check in database using query from model. lets say 'column ID' should be check in 3 times in different table. and there is +- 200 row in a single excel file.

Comment: you can use ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); but @Alex is also right.

Comment: Jeez and it took an hour to process?!

Comment: @Alex yes, it is. but it was run for less than 5 minutes, once! yes, only once.
i dont know where is the problem is, why it took an hour to process, lol

Comment: I'd suggest looking into that if you plan on using this in a live environment. But I know reading Excel files is usually cluncky.

Comment: Dont use it in your frontend code.. because you should be doing processing off-thread in a task queue or cron job which is run on cli, then it wont time out.

Comment: i'm pretty sure you should overhaul your code - because modern readers like `phpspreadsheet`are pretty quick in reading xls files and processing those lines should never ever take about an hour... (i suggest you open a new thread with your codebase - maybe somebody can help you)